# wpf control with multiple panels

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

I am looking for a wpf control for which I would be able to have some kind of navigation.
I need control so that if I have 5 textboxes for example, I can put each textbox in each page and the control will give me some capability to navigate between the pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you reckon like a wizard? If so `TabControl` already gives you what you seek. On pages you can achieve this using Master Page "Page 1" with a textbox on top and `Frame` below which actually navigates to Page2 / 3 / 4 / 5 keeping the textbox same throughout.